# If I use listing package, I cannot use listing environments, how could I use both?

Tags: listings, listingsutf8

If I use listing package, I cannot use listing environments. How could I use both?

In the next code Im using UTF8 and listing, but an error appears. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}


\begin{document}


\lstset{language=Matlab,%
    %basicstyle=\color{red},
    breaklines=true,%
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
    showstringspaces=false,%without this there will be a symbol in the places where there is a space
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red}, %some words to emphasise
    %emph=[2]{word1,word2}, emphstyle=[2]{style},    
}


\section*{Matlab Code}

\lstinputlisting{ejercicio.m}


\end{document}
```

At the end I use my Matlab archive that I need to import.

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing? The only error I get is because I don't have `ejercicio.m`.  Also consider using `\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}`. I needed to download the `mode` package form the web, but for Matlab it works nicely.

Comment: @PeterGrill I think this is a working example and the OP is saying that an additional `\begin{lstlisting}`...`\end{lstlisting}` doesn't work.  It should work though.

Comment: @PeterGrill the error that I am seeing is this                                                             "! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\expandafter\lst@FillFixed@\fi not 
set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                       "                                      Another thing is that when I dont use the package [UTF8]{inputenc}, the code works nicely.